# loop the program until 100 exit

Tags: bash

I have java server run as this command

```
java  -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseG1GC  -cp "XX"
```

we are planing to run this java from a bash script which check if the exit code of this process is 100, restart the process and keep the server running, and if the exit code was 0 process will die and process stopped

Thanks

Comment: What if the exit code is something *other* than 0 or 100? Do you run it again, or do something else?

Answer (score 0):

In bash you check the exit code of a command by reading the special var $? value.

Example:

```
$ ls .bash_profile
.bash_profile
$ echo "$?"
0

$ ls non-existing-file
ls: cannot access 'non-existing-file': No such file or directory
$ echo "$?"
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
while true; do
    java  -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseG1GC  -cp "XX"
    rc=$?
    case $rc in
        0)   break ;;
        100) : ;;    # no-op, keep looping
        *)   echo "unexpected exit status $rc" 2>&1; exit $rc ;;
    esac
done
echo "process complete"
```